# Cambiar clase de boton segun clase del body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer: https://material-ui.com/es/components/buttons/#outlined-buttons como ven, al cambiar de modo, los botones tambien cambian, como que se invierten los colores.
Yo tengo los estilos ya creados segun el modo que esté, pero no se como hacer para que estos cambien.
Quiero saber si me pueden ayudar. tengo que hacer que si el `body` tiene la clase `dark-mode` añada un style. este es mi codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('dark-mode');
// document.write( '<br>', item.classList );

// if (true) {}
var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("waves-effect waves-light btnoutline outline");
for(var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++)
    elemento[i].className = "waves-effect waves-dark btnoutline outline";

</script>
```

Mi idea es con el if comprobar, si está la clase `dark-mode` cambie eso. **TIENE QUE COMPROBAR SI EL BODY TIENE LA CLASE `DARK-MODE`**

`<body class="dark-mode">...` **ACA ENTRARÍA AL IF, Y CAMBIARÍA LOS ESTILOS.**

`<body>...` **ACA NO ENTRARÍA AL IF, Y CAMBIARÍA LOS ESTILOS.**

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer: https://material-ui.com/es/components/buttons/#outlined-buttons como ven, al cambiar de modo, los botones tambien cambian, como que se invierten los colores.
Yo tengo los estilos ya creados segun el modo que esté, pero no se como hacer para que estos cambien.

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer: https://material-ui.com/es/components/buttons/#outlined-buttons como ven, al cambiar de modo, los botones tambien cambian, como que se invierten los colores.
Yo tengo los estilos ya creados segun el modo que esté, pero no se como hacer para que estos cambien.

Comment: La solución más eficiente parece más de CSS que JavaScript.

Comment: Como sería eso, tienes algun documento o algo que lo explique?

Comment: updateupdateupdate

Comment: Es sólo una sugerencia. No serviría como respuesta ya que lo quieres hacer con javascript, pero con CSS es más simple y no necesitas funciones. Algo como `button { color: dark; background: light; }` para el body sin dark mode y más adelante ahora para dark mode: `body.dark-mode button { color: light; background: dark; }` obvio adaptarlo a tus estilos y clases pero la solución es simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```
var is_dark=document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("dark-mode");var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("waves-effect");for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){if(!is_dark){elements[i].classList.remove("waves-light");elements[i].classList.remove("btnoutlinelight");elements[i].classList.add("waves-dark");elements[i].classList.add("btnoutlinedark")}else{elements[i].classList.remove("waves-dark");elements[i].classList.add("waves-light");elements[i].classList.remove("btnoutlinedark");elements[i].classList.add("btnoutlinelight")}}
```

Gracias al usuario https://stackoverflow.com/users/8557632/mido-elhawy de stackoverflow.com:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626899/change-button-class-according-to-body-class/62627369

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar `classList` y sus métodos:

- Contains
- Add

Entonces para verificar si el `body` tiene la clase deseada haces esto:

```
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let boton = document.getElementById("id-del-boton");
```

Ahora con un condicional lo comprobamos

```
if (body.classList.contains("la-clase")) {
    boton.classList.add("regla-css-para-boton");
}
```

**Fuente de consulta**

- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

**EDICIÓN**

Para este ejemplo:

- La etiqueta body tiene una clase
- El botón desde el inicio a través de una clase tiene estilos agregados
- Dentro del código de JavaScript, si la etiqueta body en su lista de clases tiene una en específico, entonces le agrego una nueva clase a su lista de clases al botón, con lo cual los estilos iniciales que este mostraba quedan anulados y en su lugar se muestran los de la clase recién agregada.

Código:

```html
    <style>
      .cuerpo {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .botones {
        background-color: orange;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid orange;
      }
      .raros {
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 3px solid yellow;
        color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
      }
    </style>
    <body class="cuerpo">
      <button class="botones">Botón</button>
    </body>
    <script>
      let cuerpo = document.querySelector('.cuerpo');
      let boton  = document.querySelector('.botones');
      
      if (cuerpo.classList.contains('cuerpo')) {
        boton.classList.add('raros');
      }
      
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy probando, pero no logro que funcione con mi codigo, ¿puede ser que el `class="dark-mode"` lo agrego asi: `document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');` y no naturalmente desde mi editor de texto y por eso no me funcione?

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer: https://material-ui.com/es/components/buttons/#outlined-buttons como ves, al cambiar de modo, los botones tambien cambian, como que se invierten los colores. ¿Creo otro tema mejor?

Comment: Gracias @BetaM por tu respuesta, ahi edité el tema con estos detalles. Agradezco tu solución, y el tiempo que te tomaste.